# Using near-api-js in React Native

Tags: react-native, nearprotocol, near

has anyone had luck using the `near-api-js` on react native / expo? I'm trying to import the library & I'm running into the following error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module ../../App from /Users/sasha/Nextwork/nextwork/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * App(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * App/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
  2 |
> 3 | import App from '../../App';
    |                  ^
  4 |
  5 | registerRootComponent(App);
  6 |
```

if I remove the near-api-js import the app loads again

followed the steps in here:

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference, as well as the wallet examples

Comment: Can you add the code where you import the library? From the error, it looks like the issue is with the path to `../../App`.

Comment: check your cache expo start -c

Comment: @josedlujan I did that, and it does not work

Comment: @John this the gist that breaks things, https://gist.github.com/alexboii/909fe221576588e803f138cbe2a53b7e

Comment: looks like react problem no the library like @John says, try this react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: Check here... the same with vue, i think the problem is your project 
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/183

Comment: thank you for the replies! but if the problem is with my project then why does it work until I add `  const { connect, keyStores, WalletConnection } = nearAPI;`?

Comment: Did you remember to import React as well? `import React from 'react';`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]